# Jquery плавное закрытие дива до определенной ширины

Tags: jquery

нашел такой пример http://jsfiddle.net/rashomon/8vLQ9/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $dscr = $('.description'),
        $switch = $('.toggle-link'),
        $initHeight = 40; // Initial height

    $dscr.each(function() {
        $.data(this, "realHeight", $(this).height());    // Create new property realHeight
        }).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: $initHeight + 'px' });

    $switch.toggle(function() {
          $dscr.animate({ height: $dscr.data("realHeight") }, 600);
          $switch.html("-");

        }, function() {
            $dscr.animate({ height: $initHeight}, 600);
            $switch.html("+");
        });
});
```

но по неведомой причине он не работает на странице битрикса

есть ли простые варианты открытия\скрытия блока?

Comment: а на битриксе подключен нужный jquery ? например 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, как оказалось, работает и на старичке 1.4.4, просто нужно использовать архаичную запись как jQuery, а не $.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.25s;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
.small {
  max-height: 10px;
  position:relative;
}
.small:after{
  content:'+';
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  padding-left:10px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-size:25px;
  background:#ccc;
  transition:0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script  src="https://angularlight.org/bin/alight_0.12.last.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div al-app>

<div class="box" al-class="small: small" @click="small=!small">
Есть несколько простыней текста\блоков на странице. Хочется чтобы по клику на стрелке вверх\вниз блок сворачивался до высоты 100рх. Есть идеи?
Есть несколько простыней текста\блоков на странице. Хочется чтобы по клику на стрелке вверх\вниз блок сворачивался до высоты 100рх. Есть идеи?
Есть несколько простыней текста\блоков на странице. Хочется чтобы по клику на стрелке вверх\вниз блок сворачивался до высоты 100рх. Есть идеи?
Есть несколько простыней текста\блоков на странице. Хочется чтобы по клику на стрелке вверх\вниз блок сворачивался до высоты 100рх. Есть идеи?
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

вот это посмотрите - складывает этот текст в спойлер , применён ангуляр.жс

Comment: так скрывает весь блок, а мне нужно первые 5 строчек показывать